# can not see the build in iTunnes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store, application-loader

I tried send build to iTunnes Connect from Xcode and application loader. But i can not  see build in itunnes connect.

Clicked Product->Archive in xCode then I clicked upload to appstore. I sent it to appstore with success. It seems to be process at first. But after not seems builds.

I want to review for submit but i see error.

The versions are the same.

How can I fix ?

**It's solved. Apple sent an email. It gives information about the error in the mail.**

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project settings, then find your target and check the General tab.  That is where you can update your version number

If you go to the Main Menu -> Window -> Organizer, you should be able to see your app there, and the different versions you've archived.  Then on the right you can upload to the app store

Comment: I applied.Before : http://i.hizliresim.com/5L8dqM.png, After :   http://i.hizliresim.com/o0Agyo.png. Not working :(

Comment: You should've gotten an e-mail telling you that you're denied?